# Node deletion in a chained list

Tags: c, nullpointerexception

How can I change the pointer named "* FIRST" that points on the first element of a linked list if I want to delete it's first element?

-my problem is that when I delete the first node, the pointer point in the seconde node.But when I display the adress of the element I pointed on, I found that FIRST=NULL.

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{int note;
 struct personne *next;
}personne;
personne *first=NULL;

void saisi (personne *first,int mark)
{  personne *nouveau=malloc(sizeof(personne));
   nouveau->note=mark;
   nouveau->next=NULL;
   if(first==NULL)
   first=nouveau;  // here is the problem 
else
{  personne *tmp;
   tmp=first;
while (tmp->next!=NULL) tmp=tmp->next;
   tmp->next=nouveau;
}
}
void affichage (personne *first)
{int i=1;
    personne *tmp;
tmp=first;
    do
    {printf("la note %d : %d \n",i,tmp->note);
     i++;tmp=tmp->next;
    }while (tmp!=NULL);
}
void suppresion (personne *first,int n)
{personne *tmp1=NULL,*tmp2=NULL;
  tmp1=first;
while (tmp1 != NULL)
{ if ((tmp1->note) >n){
  tmp2->next=tmp1->next;
 }
  tmp2=tmp1;
  tmp1=tmp1->next;
}

}
int main()
{
int N=1,mark=0,n=0;
while (N!=4)
{ printf ("donner la note %d:",N);
  scanf ("%d",&mark);
  saisi (first,mark);
  N++;
}
  affichage (first);
  printf("donner n :");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  suppresion (first,n);
  affichage(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The trick to deleting an element in a linked list is to pass a pointer to the header pointer (two asterisks), rather than the pointer itself (a single asterisk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by dasblinkenlight, use a pointer to pointer:

```
void saisi (personne **ppfirst, int mark)
{
personne **ppnode = ppfirst;
    personne *nouveau=malloc(sizeof(personne));
    nouveau->note=mark;
    nouveau->next=NULL;
    while(*ppnode != NULL)
        ppnode = &((*ppnode)->next);
    *ppnode = nouveau;
}

void suppresion (personne **ppfirst, int n)
{
personne **ppnode = ppfirst;
personne  *pnode;
    while (*ppnode != NULL)
    {
        if((*ppnode)->note > n){
            pnode = *ppnode;
            *ppnode = (*ppnode)->next;
            free(pnode);
        } else {
            ppnode = &((*ppnode)->next);
        }
    }
}
/* ... */
    saisi(&first, mark);
/* ... */
    suppresion(&first, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- Since "first" is a global variable, you don't need to pass it as argument at each function call.

2.- At the "suppresion" method, "temp2" could be pointing to NULL when you try to call "temp2->next".

3.- You must free memory when deleting an element of your list.

4.- I don't understand well what are you asking, but if you want to delete many elements of your linked list, here is the way i would make the supression method, supposing that the method deletes all the nodes with a (mark > n):

```
void suppresion (int n)
{
    personne *tmp1=NULL,*tmp2=NULL;

    tmp1=first;

    //First check all elements except the first one
    while (tmp1 != NULL)
    { 
        if ((tmp1->next != NULL)&&(tmp1->next->note >n))
        {
            tmp2=tmp1->next;
            tmp1->next = tmp2->next;
            free(tmp2);
        }
        else
        {
            tmp1=tmp1->next;
        }
    }
    //Now go for the first element
    if(first != NULL && first->note > n)
    {
        tmp1 = first;
        first = tmp1->next;
        free(tmp1);
    }
}
```

That method searches all the elements of the array and delete all the elements that have a mark > n in just one method call; normally you create a method that deletes a concrete element and call it from a loop in another section of your code.